# How can I revert the width of a div after animation?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Here's what I'm trying to do:

A position:sticky div has a rectangle in it (id=mysquare). After scrolling a bit, the width of mysquare should shrink using jquery's animate. Then, when scrolling back up, mysquare should instantly grow back to its original width.

The problem:

The animation bit works fine. What doesn't work is reverting back to mysquare's original width. When you scroll back up after mysquare shrinks to 100px, it stays the same (when it should theoretically go back to 150px).

```js
var headheight = $(".myheading").height();

$(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > headheight) {
      //if scrolled past myheading
      //Gradually change the width of the square to 100px, from 150px
      $("#mysquare").animate({
        width: "100px",
      }, 1500);

    }
    if ($(this).scrollTop() < headheight) {
      //If not scrolled past myheading
      //Keep the square big
      $("#mysquare").width("150px");
    }
  })
});
```

```css
div.sticky {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#mysquare {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #555;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="myheading" style="height: 50px;"></div>
  <div class="sticky">Hello
    <div id="mysquare" style="width 150px;">

    </div>
  </div>

  <main style="height:500px;"></main>
</body>

</html>
```

A JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/82n16x07/7/

On a side note, mysquare seems to take up the entire width of the screen when first loaded in. Any help with that would also be appreciated.

Comment: Why not use [intersectionObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) for this? Check if your header is in view or not and then add desired animation.

Comment: @cloned I'll take a look at that as it definitely seems cleaner. However, it doesn't seem to address the root of my problem, which relates to the width of mysquare not returning after scrolling back up.

Answer (score 0):

after animation you need to remove the element and replace it to have other css applied

```js
var headheight = $(".myheading").height();

$(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > headheight) {
    
      //if scrolled past myheading
      //Gradually change the width of the square to 100px, from 150px
      $("#mysquare").animate({
        width: "100px",
      }, 1500);

    }
    if ($(this).scrollTop() < headheight) {
    
    
    var elm = document.getElementById('mysquare');
    var newone = elm.cloneNode(true);
    elm.parentNode.replaceChild(newone, elm);
    
      //If not scrolled past myheading
      //Keep the square big
      $("#mysquare").width("500px");
      
      
      
    }
  })
});
```

```css
div.sticky {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#mysquare {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #555;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="myheading" style="height: 50px;"></div>
  <div class="sticky">Hello
    <div id="mysquare" style="width 150px;">

    </div>
  </div>

  <main style="height:500px;"></main>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your initial width problem is caused by an incorrect `style` directive, with a missing colon:

```
<div id="mysquare" style="width 150px;">
```

should be:

```
<div id="mysquare" style="width: 150px;">
```

The main problem is caused by the fact that the `animate()` function is repeatedly called when the scroll condition is true, and these function calls stack up. If you wait long enough, they clear, and the box is returned to it's normal size.

To fix this, you can add a `shrunk` flag to determine if the box is shrunk or not, and check this flag to determine whether or not to issue a new `animate()` call.

```js
var headheight = $(".myheading").height();
var shrunk=false;
$(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
  
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > headheight && !shrunk) {
      //if scrolled past myheading
      //Gradually change the width of the square back to the size of the new image
           shrunk=true;
      $("#mysquare").animate({
        width: "100px",
      }, 1500);

    }
    if ($(this).scrollTop() < headheight) {
      //If not scrolled past myheading
      //Keep the square big
      shrunk=false;
      $("#mysquare").width("150px");
     }
  })
});
```

```css
div.sticky {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#mysquare {
  height: 50px;
width:150px;
  background-color: #555;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="myheading" style="height: 50px;"></div>
  <div class="sticky">Hello
    <div id="mysquare" style="width: 150px;">

    </div>
  </div>

  <main style="height:500px;"></main>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try with this. hope this works for you.

```
var lastScrollTop = 0;
$(window).scroll(function(event){
   var thisScrolltop = $(this).scrollTop();
   if (thisScrolltop > lastScrollTop){
       // write code here, when down scroll
   } else {
      // write code here, when up scroll
   }
   lastScrollTop = thisScrolltop;
});
```